# How to write a exstension map inner for a generic iterator in scala without losing type information

Tags: scala, generics

I've tried

```
exstension[A] (f: Iterator[Iterator[A]){
    def mapInner[B](f: A => B): Iterator[Iterator[B]
```

but this loses type information since if I give it a list[list[Int]] I get back Iterator[Iterator[Int]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try functors and friends:

```
trait Functor[F[_]]:
  extension [A](fa: F[A]) def fmap[B](fmap: A => B): F[B]

object Functor:
  given Functor[List] with
    extension [A](fa: List[A]) def fmap[B](fmap: A => B): List[B] =
      fa.map(fmap)
  
  given [F[_], G[_]](using F: Functor[F], G: Functor[G]): Functor[[x] =>> F[G[x]]] with
    extension [A](fa: F[G[A]]) def fmap[B](fmap: A => B): F[G[B]] =
      F.fmap(fa)(ga => G.fmap(ga)(fmap))

import Functor.given

val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

val xss = xs.map(x => List(x, x))

val fxss = summon[Functor[[x] =>> List[List[x]]]]

println(fxss.fmap(xss)((a: Int) => a * 2))
```

It's a lot of setup but likely you don't have to do it yourself and use a library like scalaz or cats where all these things are already defined.